# Cargar datos en un Input al seleccionar el dato de otro input

Tags: php, mysqli, jquery-ui

Necesito que al seleccionar el número de documento de un Input de una lista que se despliega, me cargue el nombre al que pertenece ese número de documento en otro Input. Ejemplo, al seleccionar el número de documento 12345 me cargue en otro input por ejemplo Pepito.

```js
====ajax.php===
<?php
 $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = 'root';
    $dbName = 'db_personas';

    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM persona WHERE documento LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY documento ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['documento'];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

```html
====index.php====
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:520px;margin:0px auto;margin-top:30px;height:500px;">
           
            <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="documento" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Número de Documento">
        </div>
        </div>
            <br>
           <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="nombres" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#documento").autocomplete({
                source: 'ajax.php'
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nadie me puede colaborar?

Comment: Le dejo el siguiente ejemplo espero le sea de ayuda para dar solución a lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
            $("#document").autocomplete({
                source: "persona.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#document').val(ui.item.document);
     $('#nombr').val(ui.item.nombr);
     $('#apellid').val(ui.item.apellid);
     $('#nacimient').val(ui.item.nacimient);
     $('#id_persona').val(ui.item.id_persona);
        }
            });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  Documento:  <input id="document">
  Nombres: <input id="nombr" readonly>
  Apellidos: <input id="apellid" readonly>
  Nacimiento: <input id="nacimient" readonly>
  <input type="hidden" id="id_persona">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

persona.php

```html
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
 # conectare la base de datos
    $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "nombre_db");
 
$return_arr = array();
/* Si la conexión a la base de datos , ejecuta instrucción SQL. */
if ($con)
{
 $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persona where documento like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50"); 
 
 /* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
  $id_persona=$row['id_persona'];
  $row_array['value'] = $row['documento']." | ".$row['nombres']." ".$row['apellidos'];
  $row_array['id_persona']=$row['id_persona'];
  $row_array['document']=$row['documento'];
  $row_array['nombr']=$row['nombres'];
  $row_array['apellid']=$row['apellidos'];
  $row_array['nacimient']=$row['nacimiento'];
  array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}

/* Cierra la conexión. */
mysqli_close($con);

/* Codifica el resultado del array en JSON. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

}
?>
```

Tenga en cuenta que en cada uno de los apartados $row['nombres']; lo que va dentro de los [ ] es el nombre de los atributos que tienes en la base de datos.

Comment: ok lo probare...

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió el ejemplo.

Comment: Hola excelente codigo podrias ayudarme porque este autocompleta cuando seleccionas una opcion del autocompletado pero si quisiera escribir todo y dar enter no se autocompleta sabrias como hacerlo?